# How to print prime numbers in specific format

Tags: java

I have to ask the user to input a number, and print out the prime factors.

However, this is DIFFERENT from other prime-factor codes as I need to print it in a specific format.

If the user inputs 27, I have to print out

3^3

if the use inputs 28, I have to print out

2^2*7

I know how to print out just the prime factors, so that if the user inputs 27, it would print out

3 3 3

However, I have a hard time trying to figure out how to put in the ^ sign in and the * sign. I figured I would have to count the numbers that are the same and make an if loop(possibly), but I have no clue as to how to do that.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Prime{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner input= new Scanner (System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter a number");
      int num= input.nextInt();
      String prim = "";

      for (int i = 2; i <= num ; i++) {
         while (num % i == 0) {
            prim += i + " ";
            num /= i;
         }
      }  


      System.out.println("Prime factors are: " + prim);

   }

}
```

The code above just prints out the factors, and what I have to do right now is change the format using ^ and *.

Can anyone help me out?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Side note, don't concat strings using `+=`, this is very inefficient. Use `StringBuilder`

Comment: You haven't show much effort yourself here and not explained if there are any limitations to this homework like what java version and if all of the jdk can be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the code frequency of the number is identified which is `j` variable the and the `i` represents the value than the frequency is checked for 1 and greater than 1 and its appended correctly to have the format required.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
                 Scanner input= new Scanner (System.in);
                  String result="";
                  System.out.println("Enter a number");
                   int num= input.nextInt();
                  String prim = "";

                  for (int i = 2; i <= num ; i++) {
                      int j=0;
                     while (num % i == 0) {
                        j++;
                        prim += i;
                        num /= i;
                     }
                   if(j>0){
                 if(j>1){
                   result=result+i+"^"+j+"*";
                 }else{
                     result=result+i+"*";
                 }
                }
                  }  


                  System.out.println("Prime factors are: " +result.substring(0,result.length()-1));

               }
```

Comment: This one does not work. for 16 it will print 2^2^2^2 which is 256

Comment: i have finished it check it out nice question by the way

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way would be to keep track of all prime factors, count the repetitions for each prime and then print for each prime it's repetitions after ^.

Going with object oriented design you could create your own class that holds information about factor and it's repetitions. Then when you find new factor, instead of appending the string, you either update the counter in existing object corresponding to this factor or you create new one with counter set to 1. Then you iterate over this collection and you just print for each object ^ and * between objects.

Edit: After some thought, you can just repeat division by number and count how many times you can do that. Here's the loop:

```
    for (int i = 2; i <= num ; i++) {
        int counter = 0;
        while (num % i == 0) {
            counter ++;
            num /= i;
        }
        if( counter > 0) {
            if( !firstFactor ) {
                prim += "*";
            }
            firstFactor = false;
            prim += i;
            if( counter > 1) {
                prim += "^" + counter;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `HashSet` to find the unique members in your list, and `Collections.frequency()` to count how often an element occurs in the list you already have. Then you're basically there.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Prime{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner input= new Scanner (System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter a number");
      int num= input.nextInt();
      String prim = "";
      ArrayList<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();

      for (int i = 2; i <= num ; i++) {
         while (num % i == 0) {
            l.add(i);
            num /= i;
         }
      }  

      Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<>(l);
      for (int i : s){
          if (prim.length() > 0){
              prim += " * ";
          }
          int power = Collections.frequency(l, i);
          prim += i;
          if (power > 1){
              prim += "^" + power;
          }
      }

      System.out.println("Prime factors as list: " + l);
      System.out.println("Prime factors as formula: " + prim);
   }

}
```

Output for 28:

```
Prime factors as list: [2, 2, 7]
Prime factors as formula: 2^2 * 7
```

Comment: This looks good to me, maybe for completeness if 0 or 1 is given something should be printed for them to

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: That's a good point. Handling edge cases graciously would indeed be nice. Another such edge case would be negative inputs.